# Selenium div drop down list - element not visible

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to press a button to send an input. My problem is that Selenium seems not to find it although its displayed on the screen when I open the list.

The button that opens the list:

```
<input type="button" id="opensDiv" value="Actions" style="width: 137px; padding: 1px 2px;" class="ButtonOn" onclick="dropdowns.get(0).toggle();" onmouseover="dropdowns.get(0).menuenter();this.className='ButtonOn';" this.classname="ButtonOff" ; "=" ">
```

The list itself:

```html
<div id="dropdown-list" class="dropdown-list" style="display: none; top: 157px; left: 1696px; width: 161px; padding-top: 24px;">
  <div class="dropdown-list-wrap">
    <div class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown-list').style.display ='none';var w = document.getElementById('elem').contentWindow;w.eval('execute(somethingHere)');">somethingHere</div>
    <div class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown-list').style.display ='none';var w = document.getElementById('elem').contentWindow;w.eval('execute(somethingHere)');">somethingHere</div>
    <div class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown-list').style.display ='none';var w = document.getElementById('elem').contentWindow;w.eval('execute(ButtonINeed)');">iNeedThisButton</div>
    <div class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown-list').style.display ='none';var w = document.getElementById('elem').contentWindow;w.eval('execute(somethingHere)');">somethingHere</div>
    <div class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown-list').style.display ='none';var w = document.getElementById('elem').contentWindow;w.eval('execute(somethingHere)');">somethingHere</div>
    <div class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown-list').style.display ='none';var w = document.getElementById('elem').contentWindow;w.eval('execute(somethingHere)');">somethingHere</div>
    <div class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown-list').style.display ='none';var w = document.getElementById('elem').contentWindow;w.eval('execute(somethingHere)');">somethingHere</div>
    <div class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown-list').style.display ='none';var w = document.getElementById('elem').contentWindow;w.eval('execute(somethingHere)');">somethingHere</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I already tried changing visibility with JavaScript:

```
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, iNeedThisButton);
```

Tried just clicking it after opening the list:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'iNeedThisButton')]")).click();
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(iNeedThisButton).click().build().perform();
```

NOTE: This list is inside an iframe Iv'e already entered.

EDIT: this is the iframe its within:

```html
<iframe id="Actionsdb" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;width: 0px;height:162px;z-index:99;margin-left:7px;margin-top:19px;" src="plain.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: What's the error message? – Selenium simulates user interaction and cannot "click" an element that's not within viewport, so `scrolling="no"` (or `visibility:hidden`!?) might cause the error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),'iNeedThisButton')]"}
I'm sure the xpath is correct because I have tried looking for the element through the Chrome web tools using $x and it did find it.

Comment: OK, in case it's out of viewport, `display:none` or `visibility: hidden` it would have been `element not visible`, not `no such element`... (Chrome dev tools don't necessarily help, because dev tools find hidden and out-of-viewport elements). So it has to be something else. `div#dropdown-list` is in the DOM? `driver` is set up correctly?

Comment: It (kind of) was the driver: You need to switch the driver to that iframe first. Just as you would do with, say, an additional tab. You need to switch back afterwards to perform any action in the frame's parent. I posted an answer, feel free to accept if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to that iFrame, e.g. by id:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Actionsdb")
```

Please note you might need to switch back afterwards.

Comment: I already know how to frame switch and I have already used it a couple times in my current code, no matter what I do it never detects that iframe too.

Comment: Well, `no such element` pretty much sums it up: The DOM the driver uses does not contain the DIV... if it's not the frame it's something else, but I need a full example to help, I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

try moving to element then scrolling a little with javascript ("window.scrollTo(0,-15)")
then click the element
a python sample looks like this

```
el=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),' "+category+"')]")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,-15)")
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),' " + category + "')]").click()
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the iframe has scrolling='no'

Comment: I'd suggest not to use `time.sleep()`, but Seleniums [waitFor()](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Answer (score 0):

In such situations you should use sendKeys method in the following way.

```
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
//do this until you reach your element and then do the following
WebElement.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
```

Comment: unfortunately keys don't affect it.